# PHPUnit - Mocking nested objects of the same type

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Say I have an object of type Config, which more or less stores a bunch of key/value pairs. If the value is an array, it converts the array to a new Config instance, storing the array's values within. Naturally, this can go on indefinitely with multiple levels.

What would be the best approach to mocking this type of object? I'm fairly new to PHPUnit, so it is very possible that a very straightforward solution exists, but currently I'm not sure how to proceed.

Based on my experience so far, creating a mock of Config does not propagate to the contained Config objects as well (in my __set() magic method, it is basically calling `new self($array)` when it reaches the nested array in `$data`.

Here's an example of how the object should behave:

```
$data = array(
    'one' => 'unus',
    'two' => 'duo',
    'three' => array(
        'a' => 'alpha',
        'b' => 'beta'
    )
);

$config = new Config($data);

// I should be able to do this:
echo $config->three->a;          // Outputs "alpha"
echo get_class($config->three);  // Outputs "Config"
```

Comment: You must call `$this->getMock` for each mock instance, but `Config` is using `new` directly. You'd need to set expectations on the mocks anyway. Can you provide an example test where you think you'll need mocks? It seems you should just use these objects as-is since they are simple data holders.

Comment: Why do you want to mock this object? It seems to be just a data object. I would create a new real Config object and pass it some fake data.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much context to the question to write the test, but my understanding is in it's most simple of terms, you want to be able to navigate through the '->' to reach the value you want.

Look into using new StdClass

For example

```
$config = new StdClass;
$config->three = new StdClass;
$config->three->a = 'alpha';
```